# Как запретить перетаскивание корневых элементов в TreeView

Tags: delphi

Хочу сделать перетаскивание элементов из одной ветки в другую. и в принципе получилось, сделал следующим образом DragOver:

```
 procedure TForm3.RzTreeView1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
      State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
    var
      Node, SelNode: TTreeNode;
    begin
      Node := rzTreeView1.GetNodeAt(x, y);
      // находим узел-приемник
      Accept := (Sender = Source) and (Node <> nil);
      if not Accept then
        Exit;
      SelNode := rzTreeview1.Selected;
      while (Node.Parent <> nil) and (Node <> SelNode) do
      begin
        Node := Node.Parent;
        if Node = SelNode then
          Accept := False;
      end;
    end;
```

Но теперь я могу и корневые элементы перетаскивать куда попало, можно как то запретить и разрешить только перетаскивания подэлементов из одной ветки в другую?

P.S. если кто не понял то хочу запретить делать так - [image]

И разрешить только так [image]

Answer (score 1):

Подпишитесь на событие дерева DragStart (не помню точно названия, давно с Делфи не работал), а в нем отменяйте перетаскивание, если `rzTreeview1.Selected.Parent = nil`.

Если такого события нет, то прямо в процедуре DragOver делайте эту проверку и устанавливайте `Accept := false` (что, конечно, менее красиво, т.к. лучше пользователю даже не давать начинать перетаскивать ноду).